# Is there a safe way to install Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I'm very new to using linux so I've got a few questions that might seem basic. I've got an Nvidia GTX950 graphics card, which does well with windows and its effects and animations, but I've noticed that in ubuntu simple things like showing activities can bring framerate down dramatically if I've got a lot of windows open. Minecraft, which AFAIK should run slightly better on Ubuntu runs 20FPS lower too.

1. Does Ubuntu not install graphics drivers automatically?
2. Is there a way to install Nvidia drivers safely and easily? I had tried a few months ago but if I remember correctly it broke the entire OS and I had to boot into recovery mode, but couldn't fix anything so I just switched back to windows.

As stated earlier I've never dealt with graphics drivers before so I'd be grateful for as much of an in-depth/ExplainItLikeIm5 answer.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to install Nvidia drivers.

1. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.
2. Go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and select a recommended driver.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ubuntu not install graphics drivers automatically?

Yes, it does. That is... it will use the open source version of drivers and not 3rd party drivers as those are not available on installation. On the 20.04 installation the nVidia drivers are incorporated in the installer for an easier installation.

During normal operation installing the 3rd party version of drivers is up to the user.

> Is there a way to install Nvidia drivers safely and easily?

Use the graphical front end.

> I had tried a few months ago but if I remember correctly it broke the entire OS and I had to boot into recovery mode, but couldn't fix anything so I just switched back to windows.

That can always happen so not just when installing drivers. The thing to do here is find out how to fix your system (because it IS fixable): either from a live session or grub rescue. Unless it is actual hardware failure it can be fixed and there is no need to re-install. Just a matter of getting to know your operating system.